# Positioning a div dynamically to create tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to show a `div`(like a `tooltip` with some custom content like image & text) when there is onhover on a link. 
Like in Facebook, when you hover over someone's name, you get their short profile details.

I want to use a single `div`(with updated content) for all the links on the page.
To implement this I need to know how to position my `div` next to the link dynamically through JavaScript.

Looking to support all major browsers

Comment: Can you please provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

why not just use the `title` attribute? I know you can't have markup in the `title` attribute but you can use great jquery plugins like [Tip Tip](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin) or [Tooltip](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html) to get very pretty tooltips.

Otherwise these libraries do everything for you, you can just hack the source and replace the title attribute with your div. I.e. back it so that the title attribute contains the `id` or `class` of the `div` element that contains your data and just display the `div` within the tooltip div.

This [Coda Popup Bubbles](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-popup-bubbles/) plugin also seems to use a div and converts it to a popup so it may help though it seems it's from 2008. I don't know if it's being maintained or updated.

Otherwise the only option you have is `onMouseOver` for each of the elements, get the mouse position and absolute position your div to the mouse position. That would be the simplest implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/polomoshnov/TedJy/)?:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a').hover(
            function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    p = $this.position(),
                    w = $this.width(),
                    h = $this.height();

                var $tooltip = $('<div id="tooltip">').css({
                    display: 'inline-box',
                    position: 'absolute',
                    left: p.left,
                    top: p.top - h - 5,
                    background: 'yellow',
                    border: 'solid 1px black' 
                });

                $tooltip.text('Hello World!');

                $tooltip.appendTo('body');
            },
            function () {
                  $('#tooltip').remove();
            }
        );
    });
})(jQuery);
```